What is the proper word for multiples of fruit and beer?
I have seen both questions posted before. Gen X here. I believe I was instructed to use fruit and beer for plural.
I worked at a brewery and had a tough time accepting 'beers', although it is dead common today, as is the word fruits.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

See this question. Beers is appropriate for different  types of beer, or individual servings - "Two beers, please".

Does this answer your question? Is using "fruits" as the plural of "fruit" acceptable?

Or consult a dictionary. Cambridge suggests "After we've played a match, we sit and chat over a few beers." "He'd already drunk four beers before I'd finished one." Surely you're not proposing either of those is wrong?

Acceptability in language tends to change faster than most of us would like. But we don't worry that 'ye', 'forsooth', 'beshrew' and especially 'Hƿæt! ƿē Gār-Dena in ġeār-dagum', are no longer current. We're selective. And individualistic. Some people who would find 'three lagers, please', 'three coffees, please' and even 'three beers, please' unremarkable might recoil at 'three milks, please' or 'three waters, please'. There is even a term for the addition of count usages to the traditional noncount ones: countification. It can be looked up in an in-house search.

In tbe US, the plural of "beer" is most definitely "beers," but many senses of "beer" are uncountable, which means that for those senses there is no plural.  Countable senses of beer include "single-serving container of beer" (that table of five wants three beers, two gin and tonics and a pitcher of water) or "variety of beer" (I like Belgian beers).  The main sense, "a fermented grain beverage," is uncountable because it is a mass noun.  You can have some beer; if you have twice as much, you still just have some beer, or some more beer.  Eventually it becomes a lot of beer.
